# Getting Symfony2 to Work on GoDaddy without app.php

Tags: .htaccess, symfony

I got my Symfony site installed on my GoDaddy production sever. It works fine when I use the url www.amcolan.info/Symphony/web/app.php/index. I want it to set it up to work as www.amcolan.info/index.

I altered the domain to point to the folder amcolan/Symfony/web via a GoDaddy control panel. It used to point to /amcolan which contains the working version of my site. After I got that set up, I installed the following .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # Explicitly disable rewriting for front controllers
    RewriteRule ^/app_dev.php - [L]
    RewriteRule ^/app.php - [L]

    # Fix the bundles folder
    RewriteRule ^bundles/(.*)$ bundles/$1  [QSA,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    # Change below before deploying to production
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I got the code from another related question on this site and modified to my purpose. The original was intended to live in the Symfony directory. I then cleared the production cache and attempted to access a page. It resulted in an Internal server error. Are there any errors in my code? You'd think this would be well documented by Sensio as I imagine 99% of all implementations would have to do this. Now I'm just getting bitter.

As suggested, I tried the following code that came with Symfony:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    <IfModule mod_vhost_alias.c>
        RewriteBase /
    </IfModule>

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I also tried:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    #<IfModule mod_vhost_alias.c>
        #RewriteBase /
    #</IfModule>

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I got the same error as before with both. To make sure I was getting to the directory, I added a index.php file to it and I was able to access it.

**Update 2**

After rooting around some more about goDaddy specific issues, I found a post on a goDaddy forum saying the RewriteEngine is already on. I deleted that code without affect. I then decided to try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.amcolan.info/app.php/index [QSA,L]
```

That got it to work although I suspect not correctly. I had first tried it without the index after app.php/. That got me into symfony, but generated a get error. It appeared to be because of a null argument so I added the index. So, regardless of what someone might enter after www.amcolan.info, it's going to go to the index. Once you are on a Symfony page, you can navigate to other pages in the site. So now I have three new questions:

Any idea to where the web server is pointing when it reads the .htaccess file? You would think in the /web directory as that's where the file lives. Since just specifying app.php instead of the full path didn't work, it must not be the case. Would it be the base of my site?

After the successful redirection of www.amcolan.info, the resulting displayed URL is www.amcolan.info/app.php/index. I'd like to not see the /app.php in the URL, but I suspect that's not possible in as much as it is the actual destination. Is that a correct assumption?

How do I get www.amcolan.info/somepage to go to www.amcolan.info/app.php/somepage rather than the hard coded index?

**Update 3**

I thought I was stuck, but then I tried:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php/index [QSA,L]
```

That got rid of having to use the full URL and now the destination pages no longer display the app.php. I have a new problem: just specifying www.amcolan.info causes the get error mentioned above. Specifying www.amcolan.info/somepage no longer takes me to the index, but to the specified page. Stay tuned, I may be able to solve my last problem with a little more digging.

**Update 4**

I fixed the last problem by adding the following to my routing file:

```
nopage:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: ZetchoAmColAnBundle:Default:index }
    requirements:
        _method:  GET
```

I think I'm a happy camper now.

Comment: the document root should point to the `web` directory and the delivered .htaccess in the `web` directory should do the job well.

Comment: @Pazi, by delivered, do you mean the code that came with the Symfony download?

Comment: Yes, it comes with the standard installation.

Comment: @Pazi: it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

index action is not necessary. You can easily configure any action for root routing as well.

Here is my full .htaccess file on GoDaddy that finally works. It works only for prod config (app.php), app_dev.php is not working well, but that is OK for me since it is used for production environment.

```
DirectoryIndex app.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php/ [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```